# How does path_lookup in linux kernel work?

Tags: linux-kernel

Does we need to give the complete path or just the name of the object(file /directory), Does it take care of mounted directory in the path and what does LOOKUP_FOLLOW means ?

Comment: Doesn't look like a programming question. Might want to migrate to [Linux Stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @asgs this is a pure programming question, about how kernel function works. Why there is a need to confuse an author, if you don't understand the question?

Answer (score 2):

As you might know, path_lookup is used for finding a dentry corresponding to a path name string. The search would go in the following way:

```
245      dentry 0
246     +---------------------+   rcu-walk begins here, we note d_seq, check the
247     | name:    "/"        |   inode's permission, and then look up the next
248     | inode:   10         |   path element which is "home"...
249     | children:"home", ...|
250     +---------------------+
251               |
252      dentry 1 V
253     +---------------------+   ... which brings us here. We find dentry1 via
254     | name:    "home"     |   hash lookup, then note d_seq and compare name
255     | inode:   678        |   string and parent pointer. When we have a match,
256     | children:"npiggin"  |   we now recheck the d_seq of dentry0. Then we
257     +---------------------+   check inode and look up the next element.
258               |
259      dentry2  V
260     +---------------------+   Note: if dentry0 is now modified, lookup is
261     | name:    "npiggin"  |   not necessarily invalid, so we need only keep a
262     | inode:   543        |   parent for d_seq verification, and grandparents
263     | children:"a.c", ... |   can be forgotten.
264     +---------------------+
265               |
266      dentry3  V
267     +---------------------+   At this point we have our destination dentry.
268     | name:    "a.c"      |   We now take its d_lock, verify d_seq of this
269     | inode:   14221      |   dentry. If that checks out, we can increment
270     | children:NULL       |   its refcount because we're holding d_lock.
```

So the answer to the first part of question is - the full path should be specified.
About LOOKUP_FOLLOW - if specified it will follow symlinks during search.

> Does it take care of mounted directory in the path

Not sure what do you mean here.

For more details see:
http://www2.comp.ufscar.br/lxr/source/Documentation/filesystems/path-lookup.txt?a=ia64

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex.Regarding the last question , i meant how it finds out the particular dentry is a mount point in the path ?

Comment: Actually, according to documentation it must traverse mount points, how this is done exactly - i don't know. I see that there is d_mounted field in dentry struct. It is set to 1 if dentry is a mount point. I think that is how Linux separates this "mount point dentries" and jumps to new fs.